# Convert List<string> to IEnumerable<myEnum> in C#

Tags: c#, list, enums, type-conversion, ienumerable

I want to convert my List to IEnumerable, I have searched for several methods but none seems to work.

I have an enum named `MyEnum`.

My code goes:

```cs
List<string> statusFilter = new List<string>();
statusFilter.Add(Data.MyEnum.New.ToString("d"));
statusFilter.Add(Data.MyEnum.Queued.ToString("d"));
statusFilter.Add(Data.MyEnum.InProgress.ToString("d"));
```

I have tried:

1. `IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum =(IEnumerable<Data.MyEnum>)statusFilter as IEnumerable<Data.TaskStatus>`
2. `IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum=(IEnumerable<Data.MyEnum>)statusFilter;`
3. `IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum = statusFilter;`
4. `IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum = statusFilter as IEnumerable<Data.MyEnum>;`
5. `IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum = statusFilter.Cast<Data.MyEnum>()`

At solutions #1 and #2 I encounter an error:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

As for solution #4:

`IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnum` is only set to `null`.

As for solution #5:

> 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type Data.MyEnum'

I cannot convert my list into a type of `MyEnum` since it shall hold multiple values to pass to my database so I made it a string. Also, to get the numeric value of the enum why is is formatted to `ToString("d")`.

Comment: It is not clear [why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) you are converting the values to strings in the first place, but if you are absolutely sure this is how it should be, then `statusFilter.Select(v => (MyEnum)int.Parse(v))`.

Comment: ^ plus you could also use `Enum.Parse` and the string representation of the enum instead of an [even more fragile] int value.